# Cakephp retrieve data from database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to retrieve data from database using Cakephp.

Model---->User.php

```
<?php
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class User extends AppModel 
    { 
        public $name = 'User'; 


    } 


    ?>
```

Controller--->UsersController.php

```
 <?php namespace App\Controller;

    class UsersController extends AppController {

        var $name = 'Users';

        function index()    {

            $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));

        }

    }

    ?>
```

View--->index.ctp

```
<h2>Users</h2> 

<?php if(empty($users)): ?> 
    There are no users in this list 
<?php else: ?>
     <table> 
                <tr> 
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Modified</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
               </tr>

 <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
 <tr> 
    <td> 
        <?php echo $user['user_name'] ?> 
    </td>
    <td> 
        <?php echo $user['user_email'] ?> 
    </td>
    <td> 
        <?php echo $user['user_phone'] ?> 
    </td>

     <td> 
        <?php echo $user['created_date'] ?>
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <?php echo $user['modified_date'] ?>
    </td>
     <td>
         <!-- actions on tasks will be added later --> 
    </td> 
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

but its giving me the following error :

Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean 
File C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\src\Controller\UsersController.php 
Line: 11

Please if anybody could help.

The code works fine if `$this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));`is used in the controller

Comment: What version of Cakephp is?

Comment: the version is  v 0.2.9

Comment: you are using mixed versions of cakephp, your structure and controller likes cakephp3 `src\Controller\UsersController.php` because your Model is from cakephp2. This call `$this->Users->find('all')` is from Cakephp3 and this `$this->User->find('all')` is from Cakephp2, in cakephp3 view i´ll be in `src\Template\Users\index.ctp` pleasse check your version

Comment: my view is in src\Template\Users\index.ctp controller is in src\Controller\UsersController.php and model is in src\Model\User.php....where should i edit my code?

Comment: Your version is Cakephp3 try my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using mixed Versions of Cakephp. Your Model is for Cakephp2 and the Controller for Cakephp3. Cakephp2 does not use Namespaces. So depending on which Version you use, you have to update your Code.

For Cakephp2 your Controller should look something like this:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Users';

    public function index()    {
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is giving me following error:Class 'App' not found

Comment: that means you are most likely not using cakephp2

Answer (score 0):

Your version is CakePhp3 then your code should be like this:

**src\Model\Entity\User.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

}
```

**src\Controller\UsersController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));
    }
}
```

**src\Template\Users\index.ctp**

```
...
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($user->user_name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->user_email) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->user_phone) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->created_date) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->modified_date) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```